# How to get information about the logged user without using claims in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I need information like role and email of the currently logged user but since details about the account can change while logged, I've been told to not use claims. So basically I need to search in the database every time I need something about the user. How could I implement such a thing? I thought about storing the ID somewhere and look up info based on that, but I'm thinking there are some 'cooler' ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `User` property of the page. It has an inner proprty named `Identity` that contains user name of the current logged in person. There also an extension method named `GetUserId()` that can help you find user id of the current logged user.
Having user id, you can refer to the database and find more information about the user.

Consider following code that can ease extracting currecnt user id:

```
public static string ValidateAndGetUserId(IIdentity identity)
{
    if (identity == null)
        throw new ApplicationException("No User is logged in");

    var userId = identity.GetUserId();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId))
        throw new ApplicationException("No User is logged in");

    return userId;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about GetUserId(). I do need a claim for Id though (I am not using identity, just cookies), but it is ok since the Id won't change no matter what. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use claims to get information about the user, even if that information may be updated at a later date.

All you do is: after you save a users updated information, you just login them back in again & the claims will be updated with the new information.

For example:

1. user visits "my account" page.
2. user modifies their information & then clicks on the save button.
3. in you controller just after you save the users info you just log them in again.

Here is an example from a MVC 5 app that I am working on at the moment, but the idea should still work for asp.net core:

```
    // POST: MyAccount
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Host,User")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAccount([Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Country,State,TimeZone")] MyAccountVM vm)
    {

        var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            user.FirstName = vm.FirstName;
            user.LastName = vm.LastName;
            user.Email = vm.Email;
            user.UserName = vm.Email;
            user.Phone = vm.Phone;
            user.Country = vm.Country;
            user.State = vm.State;
            user.TimeZone = vm.TimeZone;

            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);

                if (currentUser != null)
                {
                   await SignInManager.SignInAsync(currentUser, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                }

                TempData["saved"] = "true";

                return RedirectToAction("MyAccount");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This is actually really interesting. I already submitted my work but I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thank you.